# jQuery sortable, on receive unwrap() element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery Sortable to sort items in connected list. Using receive() event I want to unwrap() element, before is dropped onto list.

```
<div id="main">

</div>

<div id="side">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="row">Item 1</div>
    </div>
</div>

$("#main").sortable({
    receive: function( event, ui ) {
          $(ui.item).unwrap();
    }
});

$("#side").sortable({
    connectWith: "#main"
});
```

But for some reason as soon as item is dropped onto a #main list, main element is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that time, `ui.item` is a child of `#main`. Unwrapping `.element` will not remove `#main`:

```
$(ui.item).children('.element:first').unwrap();
```